# exporting gridview to word and saving the file without user interaction

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am exporting a gridview to ms word. This I accomplished successfully, but I don't want to show the users the MS word prompt that ask the users to 
open the file or save the file on the hard drive. I just want the gridview to be exported to word and saved on the c:\ drive without any user interaction so once
 the user presses the export button, the gridview gets exported to ms word and the word file gets saved to the hard drive.

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is possible since users C:\ drive is not the same as your C:\ drive. There might be some security implication since you are saving to users root directory, but to answer your question try to use IO fileStream which save the document as *.doc extension.

[Try this from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save on the client machine then it is not allowed. User will have to accept the download for security purpose.